# Formatting S columns with percent

Tags: tables, formatting, siunitx

Why in the following tables the results of formatting of `S` columns are different, i.e. dependent on, where the column is in table? Consequently those tables have different width.

```
\documentclass{article}           
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{array}

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c c|  
                *{2}{S[table-format=2.2,
                       table-space-text-post=\si{\,\%}\ ]<{\,\%}|}
                }
    \hline
A  &    B       &   \mc{C}  &   \mc{D}  \\  \hline
xx & xx xxx     &   12.34   &   56.78   \\  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{c| 
                *{2}{S[table-format=2.2,
                       table-space-text-post=\si{\,\%}\ ]<{\,\%}|}
                c}
    \hline
A  &   \mc{C}  &   \mc{D}   &    B     \\   \hline
xx &   12.34   &   56.78    & xx xxx   \\   \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the difference is in the space between numbers and accompanied sign `\%`. Probably in formatting of `D` columns I miss something obvious :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is well known problem and it is described in `siunitx` manual in the section *7.13 Adding items after the last column of a tabular* (page 66, released 2017/11/26):

> When using the array package ‘<’ construct to insert material after an
>   `S` or `s` column, the alignment of the final column may be wrong if
>   the standard tabular row terminator `\\` is used. This is due to the
>   way that LATEX constructs tables at a low level. The incorrect spacing
>   can be avoided by using the TEX \cr primitive to end the table rows
>   (Table 48).

Applying this in the case described in my question:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{array}

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c c|
                *{2}{S[table-format=2.2,
                       table-space-text-post=\si{\,\%}\ ]<{\,\%}|}
                }
    \hline
A  &    B       &   \mc{C}  &   \mc{D}  \cr  \hline
xx & xx xxx     &   12.34   &   56.78   \cr  \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is easier to add the percent between the columns rather than appending it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\sisetup{
  table-format=2.2
}
\begin{tabular}{ccS@{\,\%\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}S@{\,\%}}
  \toprule
  A  &    B   & \mc{C} & \mc{D} \\
  xx & xx xxx & 12.34  & 56.78  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}c*2{S@{\,\%\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}}c@{}}
  \toprule
  A  & \mc{C} & \mc{D} &    B   \\
  xx & 12.34  & 56.78  & xx xxx \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

The easiest (and from my point of view the most elegant) variant is adding the units to the column title.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\sisetup{
  table-format=2.2
}
\begin{tabular}{ccSS}
  \toprule
  A  &    B   & \mc{C [\si{\percent}]} & \mc{D [\si{\percent}]} \\
  xx & xx xxx & 12.34  & 56.78  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}cSSc@{}}
  \toprule
  A  & \mc{C [\si{\percent}]} & \mc{D [\si{\percent}]} &    B   \\
  xx & 12.34  & 56.78  & xx xxx \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I know for this alternatives. I usually use your second example, however, many time  I faced with demands that `\%` should be accompanied with numbers in all rows ... (strange, of course), so I looked what is wrong with my use of`S` columns, i.e.: formatting `S` columns.